# Office.Excel и Net.Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, office-interop

В общем, на машине стоит excel 2010 и excel 2016.

Пытаюсь через `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` выполнить преобразование xls в xlsx в приложении на .Net Core и ловлю такую ошибку:

> Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Не удается найти
>   указанный файл.

Я перебрал все либы из [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) и пробовал играть с разрядностью, не не помогло...

Comment: А на какой машине стоит excel? На серверной (я так понимаю у Вас **web** приложение **net.core**)?

Comment: @bsisoft Не, у меня консольная утилита на Core. Похоже, что придется IPC делать какой-нибудь...

Comment: Пример кода можете предоставить?

Comment: @bsisoft new Application() и смерть.